# Adding several object on the same djangoform

Tags: django, postgresql, django-forms

There is this code to register devices in a database.
You fill the form with some data, like MAC, and save it.
I want to implement a function where you split up several MACs with `,`(comma) and for each MAC a new device is added to DB (this table has an autoincrement sequence).

Basically my code is:

```
for i in listmac.split(","):
form2 = form.save(commit=False)
#next_id = Net.objects.order_by('-id_seq').first().id_seq+1
#form2.id_seq=next_id
form2.mac = i
form2.save()
```

The problem:
Let's say my next id is 150.
With the code like that, if I put 3 MACs, the code tries to add 3 devices with the `seq=150`, therefore only the last one is saved.
If I uncomment those two lines, it adds correctly 150, 151 and 152, but it does not save the sequence in the autoincrement field. So if I try to insert another register directly through the database, for example, it tries to insert 151 and it gives me an error.

Comment: 1) Do not depend on autoincrement for ordering. For why  see [Create Notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html): *Notes* section. 2) By doing `form.save(commit=False)` you are making the problem worse as you are hiding the session changes from other sessions. See the link why that causes problems. 3) If you have an autoincrement column just let it do it's work without trying to override it.

Comment: Ok. But for example, I cannot change this database, it does not depend on me. When you say don't use form.save(commit=False), you mean instancing a new object? like obj1.name = form.cleaned_data('name')?

Comment: What I mean is `commit=false` does not save(commit) the object data to the database until a explicit `save()`. Therefore other database sessions will not see that data until the save/commit is done. The bigger issue is you trying to explicitly set the autoincrement(id_seq) value.  Doing that is only going to cause you issues. Just let the autoincrement(sequence) do it's work automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked without using `form.save(commit=False)`.
I did something like :

```
name = form.cleaned_data['name']

Device.create(name=name,mac=mac)
```